# gitlab ci pipeline cant be run

Tags: configuration, gitlab, cicd

can't run pipeline from Build > Pipelines > Run pipelines. but pipelines schedule work successfuly.
I'm trying to start a pipeline not from the main branch, but there are no conditions in the configuration about the branch

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
    # For debug:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always

default:
  tags:
    - t3a.large

stages:
  - tests
  - notifications

variables:
  ENVIRONMENT:
    value: "PROD"
    options:
      - "PROD"
      - "DEV"
      - "TEST"
    description: "Choose a stand. Default value 'PROD'"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiENK.png)

how to run pipeline on click Run Pipeline

Comment: I tried the workflow rules and it works fine. Irrespective of the branch I am able to trigger the pipeline using the Run Pipeline option. Are you sure your branch .gitlab-ci.yml file does have     - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"' ?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete `.gilab-ci.yml` file to get a better idea of what may be occurring.

I suspect your `.gilab-ci.yml` file has `rules` defined at the job level, but you do not include a match for `- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"` like Raghu indicates. Your screenshot seems to indicate the same. I had a similar issue because I assumed my pipeline would execute without including that same check, my configuration was set to:

```
test_job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: manual
```

Adding the final check allowed me to use the `Run Pipeline` button to trigger my pipeline:

```
test_job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: manual
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
```

Keep in mind the [workflow:rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#workflowrules) keyword controls the behavior of the whole pipeline -  your configuration states the WHOLE pipeline will be created when using the `Run Pipeline` button or when a schedule kicks off. Your `rules` configuration for your jobs may be preventing any jobs from being created when using the `Run Pipeline` button. The 'workflow' keyword is not intended to be used as a default `rules` configuration for your jobs.

**EDIT:** As an additional note, I'm not sure if your `workflow:rules` configuration is valid since you wrap the entire statement in single quotes:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"' <-- single quotes wrap entire statement here
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" <-- remove the single quotes in case this is causing issues
```